# Filter exact text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to extract some data from the [Stackoverflow 2018 Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018) data.

Basically I want to see the average salary of people programming in `C` with more than 15 years of experience (I believe the way they are calculating C earnings is wrong, since many people learn it in the University and count it as 5 years of experience).

I am no Wizard in Excel, so I tried to filter the data by `Contains` `C`, but this leaves `Objective-C` as a result.

How can I filter only `C` from the data set, without including `C#`, `Objective-C`, `C++` and etc?

The cells are formatted as:

[image]

Comment: How about just looking for `C;` at the start of each string, `;C` at the end and `;C;` anywhere else?

Comment: You could filter on `C;`. That would remove `C++`, etc, but it would still leave `Objective-C;`.

Comment: Yes @MichaelFrank is right, that's the first thing I did, and thats my issue

Comment: Please read carefully: filter for `C;` *at the **start** of the string* (i.e. the first two characters of the string), then `;C` *at the **end** of the string* (i.e. last two characters of the string) and finally `;C;` anywhere else

Comment: How can I filter at the beginning of the string in excel?

Comment: in the filter list you have the options "Begins with", "Ends with" and "Contains"

Comment: Those options dont combine...The maximum I can see is that I can use a Custom Filter, which accepts only 2 of these options

Comment: @mFeinstein, why don't you just include the expected output with the OP !!

Comment: What do you mean by OP? What expected output?

Comment: Type 'C' into the search box, then un-check the results you want to exclude

Comment: There are hundreds of combinations there